# Why elements in array of the objects are not updating?

Tags: java, javafx

while creating an application using JavaFX i faced a little problem - elements in my array are somehow not updating with changes which are made on these elements. On the start I want to point - dont pay attention on structure and model of my app - I already know It is not good and I changed it but i still dont understand why my problem existed. This how initialization of my array look like:

```
public class GameBoardAI implements IGameModel{


Random rand = new Random();
int currentPlayer = 1;
TicTacViewController tacController = new  TicTacViewController();
Button[] buttonss = new Button[]{ tacController.btn1, tacController.btn2, tacController.btn3, tacController.btn4, 
        tacController.btn5, tacController.btn6, tacController.btn7, tacController.btn8, tacController.btn9};
```

The problem is, that when I am creating the array of buttons, buttons are not connected to the view yet, so they are still nulls. And when I am trying to invoke some methods on my buttons inside I encounter a problem:

```
public void switchPlayer() {
if(currentPlayer == 1)
{              
    currentPlayer=2;
    buttonss[rand.nextInt(9)].fire();

}
if(currentPlayer == 2)
    currentPlayer = 1;
```

}

You can see here, that I am trying to get some random button, from array of buttons i created in instance variable. Here is the part of code, when buttons are located inside TicTacViewController:

```
    public class TicTacViewController implements Initializable
{

@FXML
private Label lblPlayer;

@FXML
private Button btnNewGame;

@FXML
private GridPane gridPane;

private static final String TXT_PLAYER = "Player: ";
private IGameModel game = new GameBoard();
@FXML
public Button btn1;
@FXML
public Button btn2;
@FXML
public Button btn3;
@FXML
public Button btn4;
@FXML
public Button btn5;
@FXML
public Button btn6;
@FXML
public Button btn7;
@FXML
public Button btn8;
@FXML
public Button btn9;
```

As i understood, the problem is, that when I am creating the array as instance variable, mu buttons are still null - they are not connected to the view yet. But here happens some strange thing: When I am putting array initialization inside a switchPlayer method instead of doing this as instance variable - everything is working correctly. So it seems like when I am creating array while invoking a method buttons are already connected to the view and there is no problems. And it ruins my knowledge about reference variables - why it is not working when we are creating array as instance variable?  Because i thought that even if we have a reference variables inside a array - when we will change this reference variables, they will be also changed in our array. To be more specific - even if when we are initalizing an array and buttons are not connected to the view yet, they are connecting afterwards - so when we are invoking a switchPlayer method butttons should be already connected to the view - but compiler is telling me that they are null. Can someone explain me what is the problem here? Why while invoking a method buttons are still null, as they were in array creation even if they were connected to the view afterwards?

Comment: References in other languages may work that way but in java a "reference" just contains the info where to find an object on the heap. This location behaves as a value type. When you create your array `tacController.btn1` ect. doesn't store "a way to find the object" but evaluates `tacController.btn1` and creates a copy of the memory address which at that time is still `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is a *pass-by-value* language. Object type variables are not object pointers, they merely hold a object reference (i.e. memory address). Example:

```
String str = "Hello"; // A String type variable holding reference of "Hello" string
String str2 = str; // Variable "str2" now copies the reference of "str"
String str2 = "World"; // Variable "str2" changes the reference it holds to the string "World" (in other word, it is being replaced)
```

It is frequently confused because the follow is valid:

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<>(); // Let foo hold the reference of an empty arraylist
List<String> bar = foo; // Let bar hold the reference that is held by foo
bar.add("hello");
System.out.println(foo); // Prints "[hello]"
```

This is working because `bar` has copied the object reference of the `ArrayList` from `foo`, so any manipulation to the `ArrayList` via `bar` will be reflected by `foo`, since they both hold the same object reference.

Back to your question. If `tacController` has not loaded the FXML file, all the `Button` references will be `null`. So what you are doing is to copy the `null` references and keep these `null` references in the array. Therefore, you will never be able to access the actual `Button` objects.